# How do I change the opacity of an <iframe> element with Hover?

Tags: html, css, iframe, hover

I am trying to change the opacity of an iframe element when hovering over it. Specifically, it is a soundcloud icon.

The code I have is:

```
<html>
  <body>

 <style>

 iframe:hover {
  opacity: 0.5;
}

 </style>


    <iframe allowtransparency="true" scrolling="no" frameborder="no" 
 src="https://w.soundcloud.com/icon/?url=http%3A%2F%2Fsoundcloud.com%2Fuser-755009245-417101073&color=orange_white&size=32" 
 style="width: 32px; height: 32px;">
    <iframe> 

  </body>
</html>
```

There is no change in opacity when I hover the mouse over the soundcloud icon.
If I take the 'hover' bit out, the opacity of the icon changes as you would expect.

Thank you in advance for all suggestions :-)

Answer (score 0):

I am sure you are using IE. However, Your code works fine When I open it in Chrome. What browser version are you using? Anyways,
Below code works for both IE & Chrome.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>iframe</title>
</head>

<style>
    iframe:hover {
        display: block;
        position: relative;
        opacity: 0.5;
        width: 10px;
        cursor: pointer;
    }
</style>

<body>

    <iframe src="https://w.soundcloud.com/icon/?url=http%3A%2F%2Fsoundcloud.com%2Fuser-755009245-417101073&color=orange_white&size=32" style="width: 32px; height: 32px;" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: If you have questions use the comments section. Once you reach 50 rep points.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. I am working with CoffeeCup HTML Editor. I have just found it **does** work in Chrome but **not** in Explorer 11 or Microsoft Edge. It **doesn't** work in CoffeeCup HTML Editor preview either. Is there a way to make it work across all browsers? Thank you,

Comment: Below worked for me in IE:                                                                       
 <iframe  src="https://w.soundcloud.com/icon/?url=http%3A%2F%2Fsoundcloud.com%2Fuser-755009245-417101073&color=orange_white&size=32" style="width: 32px; height: 32px;" allowfullscreen></iframe>

Answer (score -1):

Can you give more details?
Which browser, browser version and OS are you using?
What do you have should be working fine. (tried)

Comment: If you have questions use the comments section. Once you reach 50 rep points.